# Black Screen after Software Update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, nvidia

### Bug Found! See Update Below

After I install Ubuntu and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

I install the recommended software updates from the updater

and then reboot

I always get a unresponsive blinking cursor or totally black screen.

---

tty sessions are not available, nothing happens when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> thru <kbd>F12</kbd>.

and if I run in recovery from grub, or if I use nomodeset in the Linux command, it hangs and never boots

---

I've tried

- 18.04
- 20.04.1
- 20.1

---

I'm installing ubuntu on three partitions

- 256GB for /home
- 128GB for /
- 32 GB for swap

---

i have a nvidia 2080 rev 1
but noted that if i install the latest recommended drivers and restart without doing software updates, the computer starts fine!

---

ive used boot-repair from a live usb, but the problem persists and i am unable to access ubuntu or tty

---

it's been a long few days on this and i would seriously appreciate any insight

thank you!

---

## UPDATE

As marcus pointed out in the comments, this is caused by a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620

there are three workarounds mentioned on the page :

> WORKAROUND 1: disable intel microcode updates during boot
> From this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1759920
> 1/ add the boot parameter: dis_ucode_ldr to /etc/default/grub
> 2/ update-grub

> WORKAROUND 2: downgrade (and hold) intel-microcode to older version from > bionic/main
> apt install --reinstall intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1

> WORKAROUND 3: upgrade BIOS
> Asus has released updated BIOSes, which probably include the newest microcode. After upgrading workarounds 1,2 are not needed.
> Please NOTE, unlike workarounds 1,2, BIOS upgrade is permanent and cannot be (easily) reverted.

Comment: This looks similar to an issue I had on 19.10. The root cause was a microcode update:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620

Comment: @marcus i just went through all of the updates piecemeal and found the same thing. 

thank you for your comment :)